# Css and js circle countdown progress

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to create a circle that gets filled in as the timer countsdown, so if the timer was set to refresh after 10 seconds and there is 5 seconds left, only half a circle will be filled.  The closer it gets to 100%, the more the circle is filled in.  I have the code showing a filled in circle which should not be 100% filled, and as the timer is counting down, the circle moves around what looks like a central circle.

```js
 var interval = null;
 var secondsInHour = 60 * 60;
 var secondsInMinute = 60;

 $('#refresh-rate-chooser').change(function() {

     if (interval) {
         clearInterval(interval);
     }
     var countdownSeconds = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
     var countdownSecondsOriginal = countdownSeconds;
     
     if (countdownSeconds && countdownSeconds > 0) {

         interval = setInterval(function() {
             countdownSeconds--;
             var latestCountdownSeconds = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
             var percent = (countdownSecondsOriginal - countdownSeconds) / countdownSecondsOriginal * 100;
    console.log("countdownSeconds " + countdownSeconds);
    if (percent == undefined) {
     percent = 0;
    }
    var deg = 360 * percent/100;
    if (percent > 50) {
     $(".progress-circle").addClass('gt-50');
    }
             $(".progress-circle").find('.progress-circle-fill').css('transform','rotate('+ deg +'deg)');
     
             if (countdownSeconds == 0) {
                 var formElements = $('form').serialize();

                 if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") < 0) {
                     window.location.href = encodeURI(window.location.href + "?refreshrate=" + copyCountdownSeconds + "&" + formElements);
                 } else {
                     var currentHref = replaceUrlParam(window.location.href, "refreshrate", copyCountdownSeconds);
                     $('form input, form select').each(
                         function(index) {
                             var input = $(this);
                             currentHref = replaceUrlParam(currentHref, input.attr('name'), input.val());
                         }
                     );
                     window.location.href = currentHref;
                 }
             }

         }, 1000);
     } else {


     }
 });
```

```css
.countdown-progress {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em;
    background-color: #81CE97;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-circle .progress-circle-fill {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(140deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(140deg);
    transform: rotate(140deg);
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    background: #81CE97;
}

.gt-50 .progress-circle {
    clip: rect(0, 2em, 4em, 0);
}

.gt-50 .progress-circle .progress-circle-fill {
    clip: rect(0, 4em, 4em, 2em);
    background: #E5E5E5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="refresh-rate">
    <select id="refresh-rate-chooser" name="refreshRateChooser">
        <option value="0" selected>-</option>
        <option value="10">10 secs</option>
        <option value="30">30 secs</option>
        <option value="60">1 min</option>
        <option value="120">2 mins</option>
        <option value="300">5 mins</option>
        <option value="600">10 mins</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="refreshrate" name="refreshrate" value="0" />
    <div id="countdown-progress">
        <div class="progress-circle text-center">
            <div class="progress-circle-fill" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

I can't seem to workout which bit of the code is wrong. To test this, change the select option and then the circle will move. I had originally based this on a donut chart, which is probably why the calculations are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be what you want. It's not using CSS but creating SVG path by JavaScript. Please see the comments below.

For further reading:
[SVG Tutorial From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)
[Interface SVGPathSegArcAbs From W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegArcAbs)

```js
let x = 100, // center point of the circle
    y = 100, // cneter point of the circle
    r = 50, // radius of the circle
    start = 0, // start degree
    end = 360, // end degree
    fillColor = '#81CE97', // fill color of the circle
    timers = [], // all of the times
    path = document.querySelector('path'), // path element
    circle = document.querySelector('circle'), // circle element
    timeSelect = document.querySelector('select'); // select element

// clear all of the times
function ClearTimers(timers) {
  timers.forEach(function(timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  })
}

// reset the circle
function ResetCircle() {
  path.setAttribute('display', 'none');
  circle.setAttribute('display', '');
}

// calculate the point of the svg A parameters
function CalculatePoint(centerX, centerY, radius, degree) {
  // convert degree to radians
  // decrease 90 degrees to start from y axis
  let radians = (degree - 90) * 2 * Math.PI / 360.0,
      point = {
        x: centerX + radius * Math.cos(radians),
        y: centerY + radius * Math.sin(radians),
      }
  return point;
}

// create a circle
function CreateCircle(centerX, centerY, radius, startDegree, endDegree) {
  let startPoint = CalculatePoint(centerX, centerY, radius, endDegree),
      endPoint = CalculatePoint(centerX, centerY, radius, startDegree),
      largeArcFlag = endDegree - startDegree <= 180 ? 0 : 1,
      displayDegree = endDegree - startDegree;

  if (displayDegree % 360 == 0 && displayDegree != 0) {
    path.setAttribute('display', 'none');

    circle.setAttribute('display', '');
    circle.setAttribute('r', radius);
    circle.setAttribute('cx', centerX);
    circle.setAttribute('cy', centerY);
    circle.setAttribute('fill', fillColor);
  } else {
    path.setAttribute('display', '');
    circle.setAttribute('display', 'none');

    d = `M ${startPoint.x} ${startPoint.y}
         A ${radius} ${radius} 0 ${largeArcFlag} 0 ${endPoint.x} ${endPoint.y}
         L ${centerX} ${centerY}
         L ${startPoint.x} ${startPoint.y} Z`;

    path = document.querySelector('path');
    path.setAttribute('d', d);
    path.setAttribute('fill', fillColor);
  }
}

// change event of the select that create several times counting down
timeSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
  ClearTimers(timers)

  let seconds = this.value;

  // reset the circle
  if (seconds == 0) {
    ResetCircle();
    return;
  }

  // create timers
  for (let i = 0; i <= seconds; i++) {
    timers.push(setTimeout(function() {
      let deg = end * (seconds - i) / seconds;
      CreateCircle(x, y, r, start, deg);
    }, i * 1000))
  }
})

// initialize the circle
CreateCircle(x, y, r, start, end);
```

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle></circle>
  <path d=""></path>
</svg>
<select>
  <option value="0" selected>-</option>
  <option value="10">10 secs</option>
  <option value="30">30 secs</option>
  <option value="60">1 min</option>
  <option value="120">2 mins</option>
  <option value="300">5 mins</option>
  <option value="600">10 mins</option>
</select>
```